# Powershell replace value in array error

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have been trying to replace values within an array and I am currently trying to sanitize some of the values. I am trying to remove the table tags through the use of an array, or perhaps there is a better way to do the regex? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
$array = [regex]::matches($lines, "<td>(.*?)</td>")

    for($x = 0; $x -le $max; $x++){
        $array[$x] = $array[$x].value -replace "<td>", ""
    }
```

Unfortunately, I continuously get the error below:

```
    [ : Unable to index into an object of type System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = $lines | ? {$_ -match "<td>(.*?)</td>"} | % {$_.Replace("<td>", "").Replace("</td>", "") }
```

If you only want to replace , and not , just omit the second Replace.

Better yet, if you want to replace both:

```
$array = $lines | ? {$_ -match "<td>(.*?)</td>"} | % {$_ -replace "</?td>", ""}
```

In answer to your comments, this might work better:

```
$array = [regex]::matches($lines, "<td>(.*?)</td>") | Select -exp Value | % {$_ -replace "<td>(.*?)</td>", '$1'}
```

I suspect there is a better way to do this, as applying the regular expression twice seems inefficient, but I think it should work.

Okay, I think I've got it. Try this:

```
$array = [regex]::matches($lines, "<td>(.*?)</td>") | % {$_.Result('$1')}
```

Comment: hmm, this definitely replaces contents which is great, but it doesn't place it into an array. I believe it places the contents into a very long string. I need the array to do a .getCount and then run through another loop to build a csv. I have tried doing $array = @() and running the code snippet, but can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that $lines is an array, $array is one as well. To test, I populated $lines with:
    $lines = Get-Content test.html

Comment: $lines is currently one long string and I break each <td> line into one row within the array using the [regex] command

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this, but I came up with this, combining your first RegEx query, with the '$1' trick suggested by mjolinor: 

$array = [regex]::matches($lines, "<td>(.*?)</td>") | Select -exp Value | % {$_ -replace "<td>(.*?)</td>", '$1'}

Comment: I just updated my answer with what I think is a much better solution.

Comment: sweet sweet success! Thanks a bunch. I used your answer: $array = [regex]::matches($lines, "<td>(.*?)</td>") | % {$_.Result('$1')} and changed my function to use $max = $array.get_length() instead of get_Count

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = $lines -replace '<td>(.*?)</td>','$1'
```